# serverless parameter value is undefined when running serverless deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

Followed https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-secrets-api-keys to add a parameter value with the key `abc` in my serverless service/app (via the UI dashboard) but getting this error: `${param:abc} not defined` when running `serverless deploy`. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

serverless.yaml config snippet

```
frameworkVersion: "1.83.2"

provider:
  name: aws
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true
  runtime: python3.8
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    abc:${param:abc}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't be able to help with this answer on StackOverflow, because our support team will need to work with you and your Serverless.com organization specifically - so please reach out via the support channels in the app, or DM me in Slack.

Parameters can be configured at the Service-level, and optionally overridden at the specific `stage` - so it would help to verify that this parameter is set within the `service` or `stage` you are deploying to.

Comment: do you have link to join the slack channel?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...... seems like you are trying to create an environment variable there if I am not mistaken. You are trying to assign value to your environment variable "abc" which is not defined, There are few ways you can pass the value to your environment you could have an environment file where you can supply these parameters to your service like the following one envFilePath: "../../shared/environments/env.json"
Then You will be able to pick the value and set it to the variable using ${file(${self:custom.envFilePath}):abc} or another option you could directly type the value in your yml. You can even read the value from a ssm parameter also.